# Do All Uploads Base64 Encode?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, encoding, base64

I'm trying to understand the concept of uploading and how Base64 may/may not relate.

When I have a an HTML form (with the multipart attribute) that uploads an attachment (e.g. an image/executable) upon submission - does the browser Base64 encode it first, and then send that to a processing page? Or does the browser send raw binary data to the target page?

Comment: This is something you can easily check yourself with a network sniffer, and even various browser plugins.